# Get length of a instance of string class using recursion in C++

Tags: python, c++, string, recursion

I am writing a recursive function to find the length of a string in C++. It's a simple problem and I wrote two functions in C++ and one in Python.

> First

```
int length(char *str) {
    if (*str == '\0')
        return 0;
    return 1 + length(str + 1);
}
```

> Second

```
int get_size(string str, int i) {
if (str[i] == '\0')
    return 0;
return 1 + get_size(str, i + 1);
```

}

> Python

```
def length(string):
    if not string:
        return 0
    return 1 + length(string[1:])
```

They all work fine. But, what I want is to rewrite the second function such that there is not any need for an `integer` argument like the first one. I don't want to use `static` and `global` variables and any library functions except `string` class instance either. How do I rewrite the second function as the first one?

Comment: Why exactly are you doing this? Besides just being able to use `std::string::length()` directly, recursing over input data is always a dangerous idea. If you insist, however, the idiomatic way to do this in C++ would be to use an `std::string::const_iterator` pair.

Comment: also note that `std::string` is not terminated by `\0`. It can contain `\0` in the middle. For such a `std::string` your `length` will return the wrong length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++-equivalent to pythons `string[1:]` is [`std::string::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr):

```
int get_size(std::string str) {
    if (str.empty()) // end of recursion
        return 0;

    // call recursively with substr from second to last character.
    return 1 + get_size(str.substr(1)); 
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use any library function either.

Comment: @Sherlock You can't use `std:string` without using the standard library.

Comment: @Sherlock `str.length()` is from the library. If you have constraints and requirements please note them in the question

Comment: @Sherlock In this case the second example is pointless. You can't use a part of the standard library ... without  using the standard library.

Comment: @churill I have to use string class to make a string but I am not allowed to use any string class function. I made the necessary changes in the question now.

Comment: @Sherlock You have to use `std::string` but are not allowed to use it's functions? Are you really sure this is your task? You can't do anything with an object if you are not allowed to use any of it's functions and the second example clearly uses one such function: `str.length()` (and after edit `str[i]` is still calling a function of `std::string`!). Maybe you could do some really, really dirty casts to get the internal data of the string, but that's probably not what you are supposed to do.